# 404 Page on the first visit of article in Joomla

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404

Whene i create a new article it shows 404 Page on the first visit, Then when i refresh it works.
I have SH404SEF installed and Joomla 2.5.8.
I checked Google webmaster tools and since August 404 Pages raised from 100 to 700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh404SEF` is a recipe for messiness. I can't tell you how many issues our clients have because of this horrible extension (which may be the worst Joomla extension as [this post](http://www.itoctopus.com/sh404-the-worst-joomla-extension) describes it back in 2013)

One of the major issues with `sh404SEF` is that it doesn't know the link of a certain page unless you visit a page pointing that page. So, if you have a new article, `sh404SEF` will not be able to know its link unless you have already visited a page linking to it.

Now as for your 404 pages, I think that this is a different issue - it might be related to `sh404SEF` but it's not the same issue that you're talking about - examine the 404 links closely and make see why they are not working. If you want, you can share some of these links (as an attachment) on this post so we can examine the issue.